# convert formatted C string and arguments to a wstring on windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, string-formatting, wstring

I am currently setting up the ffmpeg logger to use our own logging mechanism on Windows and I have issues with the formatted part of the output.

The callback signature is :

```
void(*callback)(void * handle, int dbglvl, const char * fmt, va_list vl);
```

and I try to write into a `wstring` using the helper :

```
 std::wstring asStdWstring(const char *fmt, va_list vl)
 {
      int required_length = _vscprintf(fmt,vl) +1; 
      required_length++; // include null terminating character

      if(array_length < required_length)
      {
        array_length = required_length;
        delete char_array;
        char_array = new char[array_length];
      }

      sprintf_s(char_array,array_length-1,fmt,vl);
      char_array[array_length-1] = '\0';

      std::wstring wstr(char_array, char_array+ array_length);
      return wstr;
 }
```

unfortunately the formatted part is giving unexpected result. For a call

```
some_callback(handle, 0,"Bitrate %d is extremely low, maybe you mean %dk\n", 10,10);
```

I obtain the string

> Bitrate 1232440 is extremely low, maybe you mean -858993460k.

Comment: -858993460 == 0xCCCCCCCC, 1232440 = 0x12CE38,  40= 0x28 & 60=0x3C, your call back looks like "void(*callback)(void *, int, const char *, va_list);" but the call looks like some_callback("Bitrate %d is extremely low, maybe you mean %dk\n", 40,60); ie I assume you are missing the first two params in your example?

Comment: yes indeed. let me edit

Comment: as a side note the params are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my culprid. It seems the "secure" versions of sprintf from microsoft are not compatible with `_vscprintf` (from microsoft too). Thus reverting back to `_vsnprintf` instead of `sprintf_s` gave the expected results

```
std::wstring asStdWstring(const char *fmt, va_list vl)
 {
      int required_length = _vscprintf(fmt,vl) +1; 
      required_length++; // include null terminating character

      if(array_length < required_length)
      {
        array_length = required_length;
        delete char_array;
        char_array = new char[array_length];
      }

      _vsnprintf(char_array,required_length-1,fmt,vl);
      char_array[required_length-1] = '\0';

      std::wstring wstr(char_array, char_array+ required_length);
      return wstr;
 }
```